# Adding object to last element of arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm creating a resizeable Object Array. Below is my `add` function in which I pass through the object I want to add into my arraylist.

The function works, however if someone could explain this code
`temp[theList.length] = toAdd;`

I understand that it's adding the parameter argument to the end of the new Arraylist.  But what's confusing me is the index that I pass into `temp[]`. Shouldn't I be including `theList.length + 1` rather than just `theList.length`?

```java
public boolean add(Object toAdd) {
        
    if (toAdd != null) {
            
        Object[] temp = new Object[theList.length + 1];
            
        for (int i = 0; i < theList.length; i++) {
            temp[i] = theList[i];
        }
        temp[theList.length] = toAdd;
        theList = temp;
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid type");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you understand that array indices are 0-based?

Comment: Array indices are zero-based. That means the last index is `length - 1`. Since you created `temp` with a length of `theList.length + 1` that means the last index of `temp` is `theList.length`.

Comment: BTW you should use List instead of arrays as they can grow

Comment: @David This code seems like a student exercise, so the array is probably part of the requirements.

Comment: @DavidBrossard This method looks like it is the implementation of a custom list class, used as an exercise for teaching array manipulation, and using `ArrayList` would defeat the purpose of the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation for the add method**:

Assume, the size of the `theList` is 10.

They have created an `temp` array which takes size as `theList + 1`, so size of `temp` is `11`.
Now, objects are added to the `temp` except for the last element `tem[10]`.

For adding the last element, you can use any of the 2 ways:

```
temp[theList.length] //temp[10]
```

Or

```
temp[temp.length-1] //temp[10]
```

They used the 1st way to add the `toAdd` object.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a standard method [`Arrays.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(T%5B%5D,%20int)) which immediately creates a copy of the input array with the new size (in this case, the length is increased):

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

//...

public boolean add(Object toAdd) {
        
    if (toAdd != null) {
        int oldLength = theList.length;
        theList = Arrays.copyOf(theList, oldLength + 1);
        theList[oldLength] = toAdd;

        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Cannot add null object");
        return false;
    }
}
```